# Expansion of ideal gas

Tags: ideal-gas

Consider an ideal gas in a chamber (A), separated from another chamber (B) by a diaphragm, in the following two situations:

(1) Instantaneously burst the diaphragm
(2) Plug in an isentropic nozzle so that the gas escapes gradually

Are the two cases identical? I believe there should be some work done in the second case, because the opposing pressure in chamber B increases gradually, so the work done by the gas would increase as it reaches steady state. Is this reasoning correct, or should both cases have zero work done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the walls of the container are perfect insulators the final steady states must be indentical, as they are determined only by the gas's volume, internal energy and particle number, all of which are the same in both cases. (Internal energy is the same as no energy is transfered to the gas from outside.)

I think the confusion arises because *one part* of the gas is doing work on *another part* of the gas during the expansion in the second case, but the net work done by the gas as a whole is still zero.